# how to dd() result from stored procedures in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stored-procedures

I need to accept data from from SP. I calls SP from web API(laravel).

```
                //get no reg from system
                $response3 = $client->post($webapi_url . '/api/max_noreg', [
                //     'json' => [
                'form_params' => [
                    'tglreg' => '2020-07-20 00:00:00',
                ],
                'cookies' => $cookieJar,
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);

            dd($response3);
```

here's my SP

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spmcu_Reg_MaxNoRegByTglTrans] 

    @TglTrans datetime

AS

SELECT NoRegMax = IsNull(MAX(NoReg),'') FROM mcu_Reg
WHERE TglTrans = @TglTrans
```

here's my API controller

```
public function max_noreg(Request $request)
{
    // $credentials = [
    //     'tglreg' => $request->tglreg
    // ];

    // $tglst = '2020-07-19 00:00:00';

    $referral_registers = DB::connection('as_api')
        ->select('EXEC spmcu_Reg_MaxNoRegByTglTrans ?', 
        array($request->tglreg));

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $referral_registers
    ]);
}
```

and when i dd() the response, it return this

> Response {#590 ▼
> -reasonPhrase: "OK"
> -statusCode: 200
> -headers: array:6 [▶]
> -headerNames: array:6 [▶]
> -protocol: "1.1"
> -stream: Stream {#582 ▶}
> }

and i want it return result from SP like example below

```
IDU2007200003
```

i've check my sql profiler, the logs like this

> declare @p1 int
> set @p1=1
> exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(4000)',N'EXEC spmcu_Reg_MaxNoRegByTglTrans @P1',N'2020-07-20 00:00:00'
> select @p1

pls help me to get my sp result and pass it to dd to test if i get the value

and below are my dump value

```
    GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response Object
(
    [reasonPhrase:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => OK
    [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 200
    [headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 127.0.0.1:8000
                )

            [Date] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mon, 20 Jul 2020 05:36:30 GMT
                    [1] => Mon, 20 Jul 2020 05:36:30 GMT
                )

            [Connection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => close
                )

            [X-Powered-By] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PHP/7.2.19
                )

            [Cache-Control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-cache, private
                )

            [Content-Type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => application/json
                )

        )

    [headerNames:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => Array
        (
            [host] => Host
            [date] => Date
            [connection] => Connection
            [x-powered-by] => X-Powered-By
            [cache-control] => Cache-Control
            [content-type] => Content-Type
        )

    [protocol:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 1.1
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
        (
            [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #572
            [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
            [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
            [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
            [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Is your SP returning exactly what you are expecting in your dd()? If so, instead of `dd($response3)` try echo `<pre>; print_r($response3); die();`. You must be having the expected value somewhere in the response.

Comment: i do as told, but there's no expected value among returned response. any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please do the same with `$referral_registers` before returning the response. Means put it in `print_r()`.

Comment: Try `$response3->getBody()`. GuzzleHttp has `getBody()` function that give access to response body.

Comment: print_r($response3->getBody()); it shows partial of  "print_r($response3); "

Comment: Can you show me exactly what it is giving?

Comment: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
(
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #572
    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
        (
        )

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, decode the response
`$response = json_decode($response3->getBody());`
`dd(response)`

Comment: yes...i need to decode first to dd the response..thx for your answer. hope this help others too